# SELECT latest data from 2 joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have looked pretty hard through other SQL query questions but have been unable to narrow down a response that seems to work in my case... so here goes.

I have two mySQL tables:

```
players:
pid
pname

player_stats:
pid
statdate
rank
score
```

I would like to show output of the players name and their **latest** score and rank like this:

```
player1 | rank10 | 123345
player2 | rank15 | 480993
```

I have played around with max(statdate) and GROUP BY on pname but the closest I have gotten is below, which gives me the right number of rows but not the latest date (thus not the latest rank or score).

```
SELECT p.pname, s.rank, s.score
FROM players p INNER JOIN player_stats s ON p.pid = s.pid
GROUP BY p.pname
```

as mentioned this is close but the rank/score are not always the last date's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an extra join in a subquery which separately get the latest `date` for every `pid`.

The subquery contains only two columns: `pid` and `statdate`. To get the other columns you need to join it with the other table.

```
SELECT  a.pname, b.rank, b.score
FROM    players a
        INNER JOIN player_stats b
            ON a.pid = b.pid
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  pid, MAX(statdate) statdate
            FROM    player_stats
            GROUP   BY pid
        ) c ON  b.pid = c.pid
                AND b.statdate = c.statdate
```

Comment: wow, this is why StackOverflow is such a valuable tool.  That answer is bang on and I have it up and running now.  Thank you so much for your prompt and accurate reply!